# Laravel How to Isset _GET

Tags: php, laravel

I'm still very new at Laravel.

I got problem how can I use `Isset($_GET)`?

How to get for example: http://virtualhost.com/flytrap/public/location?city=25?

Usually when at pure PHP, I always use:

```
if (isset($_GET["submit"]))
{
   $location = $_GET["city"];
}
```

to get city value. So I can use it for query at database. If I use Core PHP method I got an error.

Comment: If you had bothered to read [Laravel’s documentation on requests](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#basic-input), you would know how to do this.

Comment: oh. let me read that. i don't know requests means isset. Thanks for the heads up :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use below code

```
$location = Request::query('city', false); //insed of $_GET['city'];
```

Comment: Always Welcome My Friend :)

Answer (score 2):

This is Laravel equivalent (see http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests):

```
if (Input::has('submit')) {
    $location = Input::get('city');
}
```

But as Lalit Sharma says, you should maybe always set $location even if you have not "submit" in GET:

```
$location = Input::get('city', null);
```

null is the default value so you can ommit it or use any other value:

```
$location = Input::get('city', 'Reykjavik');
```

Comment: Thanks! it's very complete. :D