# Pass get parameter to controler in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How do I pass a get variable to a controller in Laravel?

I have:

```
$languages = array('zh');
$locale = Request::segment(1);
if (in_array($locale, $languages)) {
    App::setLocale($locale);
} else {
    $locale = null;
}
Route::group(array('prefix' => $locale), function() {
    ...
    Route::get('/search/{q}', array('as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'ProductsController@index'));
    ...
});
```

If I try to return `q` from within the controller using `Input::get('q');` I get nothing.

Comment: pls refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27012994/laravel-how-to-isset-get/27013133#27013133

Comment: You may try this code to read value from query string $location = Request::query('q', false);

Answer (score 3):

```
Route::get('/search/{q}', array('as' => 'search', 'uses' => 'ProductsController@index'));
```

the `{q}` here isn't GET variable.

you can take the value like this.

```
public function index($q)
{
     echo $q;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a GET parameter but an URL parameter. There's a little difference in that.

Url paramters will be passed (in the order they appear) to the controller action.

So all you have to do, is use the argument that gets automatically passed to the function in the controller.

```
public function index($q){
    echo $q;
}
```